# Trouble finding solution for this responsive menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this responsive hamburger menu, which works fine in google chrome. But it doesn't work on Internet Explorer. while testing in internet explorer in the mobile version, the menu shows as static. And when clicked on menu icon it doesn't collapse. I tried to find out the if its due to incompatible. But seems it's not the reason. Any direction to this will be greatly appreciated.

### Here is the code :

```
<nav class="site-nav ">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-info site-nav--icon"></i>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#project"><i class="fa fa-pencil site-nav--icon"></i>Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
```

### This is my js:

```
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open', 500);
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

### Here is my CSS:

```
.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 2%;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #3e69fe 0%, #4cd4e3 100%);
  clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
  transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;

}

.site-nav--open {
  clip-path: circle(250% at top right);
/*   display: block; */
}

.site-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.site-nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBD3;
}

.site-nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.site-nav a {
  color: #EBEBD3;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em 4em 2em 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-nav a:hover,
.site-nav a:focus {
  background: transparent;
  color: #464655;
}

.site-nav--icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  text-align: right;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

.menu-toggle {
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: .5em;
  right: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #EBEBD3;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.hamburger::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {

  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .site-nav {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    float: right;
    clip-path: initial;
  }

  .site-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
  }

  .site-nav a {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 3em;
  }

  .site-nav a:hover,
  .site-nav a:focus {
    background: transparent;
  }

  .site-nav--icon {
    display: none;
  }

}

 header {
     padding: 10px 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
     header {
         padding: 15px 0;
    }
}
 .menu-bar {
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .menu-bar span {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 24px;
}
 .main-menubar {
     position: relative;
}
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
     nav {
         margin-right: 0;
         position: absolute;
         right: 0;
         top: 47px;
         text-align: right;
         padding: 20px 0;
         z-index: 5;
         background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #4cd4e3 0%, #3e69fe 100%);
         background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #4cd4e3 0%, #3e69fe 100%);
         background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, #4cd4e3 0%, #3e69fe 100%);
    }
}
        font - size: 24 px;
    }
    .main - menubar {
        position: relative;
    }
@media(max - width: 767 px) {
    nav {
        margin - right: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 47 px;
        text - align: right;
        padding: 20 px 0;
        z - index: 5;
        background - image: -moz - linear - gradient(0 deg, #4cd4e3 0%, # 3e69 fe 100 % );
        background - image: -webkit - linear - gradient(0 deg, #4cd4e3 0%, # 3e69 fe 100 % );
        background - image: -ms - linear - gradient(0 deg, #4cd4e3 0%, # 3e69 fe 100 % );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work on IE, because IE support "clip-path" only in SVG elements. ([MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility))